# Java: Arraylist Serialization Error while Deserializing and searching for objects

Tags: java

My  Project is about library management system. 
I have to **store data into objects of class and later store them into arraylist**.
**Then I'm serializing the data**.

**I have these functions:**

1. addBook();
   -Deserialize array list
   -perform operations
   -Serialize array list
2. deleteBook();
   -Deserialize array list
   -perform operations
   -Serialize array list
3. modifyBok();
   -Deserialize array list
   -perform operations
   -Serialize array list
4. IssueBook();
   -Deserialize array list
   -perform operations
   -Serialize array list
5. returnBook();
   -Deserialize array list
   -perform operations
   -Serialize array list

My ArrayList:
    public static ArrayList bookData = new ArrayList();

My code i use to serialize:

```
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }
```

My code i use to deserialize:

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    //ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Database.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        bookData = (ArrayList<Library>) ois.readObject();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }
```

I was getting a exception becuase BufferedReader needs to be transient and that was fixed. But now,
I Think my serialization isnt working. and everytime i create a book i store its index(object Number)in a text file.
None of my searching technique is working: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception caught. I tried to do size+1 of the arraylist
but that also isnt working.

```
My code for searching. Before this the deserialization code is there.

try{
        System.out.println("_________________Search Book_________________");
        System.out.println("Enter Title of Book to Search: ");
        String title = scan.readLine();
        for(int i=0;i<bookData.size();i++)
        {
            if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()))
            {
                if(bookData.get(i).getBookId() == getObjCount())
                {
                    System.out.println("Book Found at ["+i+"]");
                    System.out.println("Displaying Book Data....");
                    System.out.println("Book Title    : "+bookData.get(i).getBookTitle());
                    System.out.println("Book Author   : "+bookData.get(i).getBookAuthor());
                    System.out.println("Book Subject  : "+bookData.get(i).getBookSubject());
                    System.out.println("Book Price    : "+bookData.get(i).getBookPrice());
                    System.out.println("No. of Copies : "+bookData.get(i).getAvailableCopies());
                    break; 
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Internal Error Caught.[1] Index Mismatch");
                    //Library.main();
                }
            }
            else{
                status=1;
            }
        }
        if(status == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Book Not Found.");
        }
```

**My full code can be found at**: https://pastebin.com/emUc9yS6
Is there any other way we can retrieve data from array list after serializing it.

Comment: Your problem is that you're using the same class to represent a library or a book.

Comment: Code to trigger modify function:
System.out.println("Enter Index of Book you want to Modify: ");
       int index=Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());
       bookData.get(index).modifyBook();

Comment: I have separated the code now

Answer (score 0):

I can't post answer but I will try to help you with your code. Firstly, you had better read about SOLID principles. Because, as I see, you have all code in one class. It isn't relate to Single Responsibility Principle. Then you have to split you Library class to Book(will represent book), Library(optional, depends on your tasks) and Book(or Library)Service(will work with library - add, delete, update, ect. books). After that you will able to test your code and you will find bugs faster. It is just my point of view.

Comment: But now I cant access method from child class

Comment: Library.java : https://pastebin.com/uSwpxQz5
Books.java: https://pastebin.com/5XHCdu4q
Try to execute

Comment: as I said, you have to create BookService. Your book as like entity. It is represent object and must not to have any methods(only getters and setters). It is responsibility of BookService.Something like this:
`public class BookService {
    private static ArrayList<Book> bookData = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addBook(Book book){
        bookData.add(book);
    }
    public void deleteBook(Book book){
        bookData.remove(book);
    }
    ...
}`

Comment: and Library doesn't extend Books

Comment: u want me to add that methods into Library.java?

Comment: Yes, I think Library will be as like service

Answer (score 0):

2 things that I have identified from your code that are causing errors :

1. BufferedReader scan is part of your library , so you try to serialize/deserialize it and hence receive errors.
2. You never seem to be incrementing the bookid.

With that said I thing you should model your Library as follows  :

Library contains Books.

```
public class Book implements Serializable
{  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 24913L; 


static int bookId=0;        // Stores ID of Books
double bookPrice;           // Stores Price of Book
int availableCopies;        // Stores Nos. of available copies
String bookTitle;           // Stores title of Books
String bookAuthor;          // Stores author of Book
String bookSubject;         // Stores Subject of Book
//StringBuffer studentName; // Stores Name of Student which issued/Returned Book.
StringBuffer issuedTo[] = new StringBuffer[1000];
//Stores all names of students which issued same book.

//Constructors
public Book()
{
    generateBookId();
}

public Book(String bookTitle, String bookAuthor, String bookSubject, double bookPrice, int availableCopies)
{
    generateBookId();
    this.bookTitle=bookTitle;
    this.bookAuthor=bookAuthor;
    this.bookSubject=bookSubject;
    this.bookPrice=bookPrice;
    this.availableCopies=availableCopies;
}

//Functions
public static int generateBookId(){
    bookId++;       //Incrementing Book Id
    return bookId;  // Returning the incremented book Id
}

public int getBookId() throws IOException{
    return bookId;
}

public double getBookPrice() throws IOException{
    return bookPrice;
}

public String getBookTitle() throws IOException{
    return bookTitle;
}

public String getBookAuthor() throws IOException{
    return bookAuthor;
}

public String getBookSubject() throws IOException{
    return bookSubject;
}

public int getAvailableCopies() throws IOException{
    return availableCopies;
}

/*public void setBookId() throws IOException{
    bookId = Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());
}*/

public void setBookPrice(double bookPrice) throws IOException{
    this.bookPrice = bookPrice;
}

public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) throws IOException{
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
}

public void setBookAuthor(String bookAuthor) throws IOException{
    this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
}

public void setBookSubject(String bookSubject) throws IOException{
    this.bookSubject = bookSubject;
}

public void setNoOfCopies(int availableCopies) throws IOException{
    this.availableCopies = availableCopies;
}

public void addBookCopies() throws IOException{
    availableCopies++;
}

public void removeBookCopies() throws IOException{
    availableCopies--;
}
```

}

And the Library as follows :

```
public class Library implements Serializable
{  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 24913L; //used to verify sender and reciever   

    public static ArrayList<Book> bookData = new ArrayList<Book>();


public void addBook(Book book)
{       
    try{
        objCount++;
        bookData.add(book);           
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }finally{
        try{
            File file = new File("Books_Index.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            int count=getObjCount();
            fw.write("\nBook Index ["+count+"] Contains Book Named: ["+book.getBookTitle()+"]");
            fw.close();
            //saveData();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }
    }

}

public void deleteBook(int index ,String title)
{
    //fetchData();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    //ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Database.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        bookData = (ArrayList<Book>) ois.readObject();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }

    int status=0;
    try{

        for(int i=0;i<bookData.size();i++)
        {
            if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()))
            {
                bookData.set(bookData.indexOf(i),null);
                    //changing the value to null so that index of books would be maintained
                    // ...to avoid left shift
                    break;                    
            }
            else{
                status=1;
            }
        }
        if(status == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Book Not Found.");
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }finally{
        try{
            File file = new File("Books_Index.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            int count = getObjCount();
            fw.write("\n Book Index ["+count+"] got deleted. Book Named: ["+title+"]");
            fw.close();
            System.out.println("Delete Operation Finished.");
            //saveData();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }
    }
}

public void modifyBook(int index,String title,double price,int availableCopies)
{
    //fetchData();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    //ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Database.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        bookData = (ArrayList<Book>) ois.readObject();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }

    int status=0;
    try{

        for(int i=0;i<bookData.size();i++)
        {
            if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()))
            {                        
                    bookData.get(index).setBookPrice(price);
                    bookData.get(index).setNoOfCopies(availableCopies);                 
            }
            else{
                status=1;
            }
        }
        if(status == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Book Not Found.");
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Modify Operation Finished.");
        //saveData();
    }
}

public void searchBook(int index,String title)
{
    //fetchData();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    //ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Database.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        bookData = (ArrayList<Book>) ois.readObject();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }

    int status=0;
    try{

        for(int i=0;i<bookData.size();i++)
        {
            if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()))
            {
                if(bookData.get(i).getBookId() == getObjCount())
                {
                    System.out.println("Book Found at ["+i+"]");
                    System.out.println("Displaying Book Data....");
                    System.out.println("Book Title    : "+bookData.get(i).getBookTitle());
                    System.out.println("Book Author   : "+bookData.get(i).getBookAuthor());
                    System.out.println("Book Subject  : "+bookData.get(i).getBookSubject());
                    System.out.println("Book Price    : "+bookData.get(i).getBookPrice());
                    System.out.println("No. of Copies : "+bookData.get(i).getAvailableCopies());
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Internal Error Caught.[1] Index Mismatch");
                    //Library.main();
                }
            }
            else{
                status=1;
            }
        }
        if(status == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Book Not Found.");
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Search Operation Finished.");
        //saveData();
    }
}

public void issueBook(int index,String title,String studName)
{
    int status = 0;
    //fetchData();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    //ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Database.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        bookData = (ArrayList<Book>) ois.readObject();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }

    try{

        for(int i=0;i<bookData.size();i++)
        {
            if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()))
            {
                if(bookData.get(i).getBookId() == getObjCount())
                {
                    //
                    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
                    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
                    //
                    //Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    //String currentDate = formatter.format(date);
                    //i++;
                    bookData.get(i).removeBookCopies();
                    //i++;
                    File file = new File("issueLogs.txt");
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                    fw.write("\n["+dtf.format(now)+"] : Book Title : "+bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()+" was Issued by Student Name"+studName);
                    fw.close();
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Internal Error Caught.[1] Index Mismatch");
                    //Library.main();
                }
            }
            else{
                status=1;
            }
            if(status == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("353");
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Issue Operation Finished.");
        //saveData();
    }
}

public void returnBook(int index,String title,String studName)
{
    int status=0;
    //fetchData();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    //ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Database.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        bookData = (ArrayList<Book>) ois.readObject();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }

    try{

        for(int i=0;i<bookData.size();i++)
        {
            if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()))
            {
                if(bookData.get(i).getBookId() == getObjCount())
                {
                    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
                    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
                    //Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    //String currentdate = formatter.format(date);
                    //i++;
                    bookData.get(i).addBookCopies();
                    //i++; //are yaar he ka kelela mi??
                    File file = new File("returnLogs.txt");
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                    fw.write("\n["+dtf.format(now)+"] : Book Title : "+bookData.get(i).getBookTitle()+" was Returned by Student Name"+studName);
                    fw.close();
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Internal Error Caught.[1] Index Mismatch");
                    //Library.main();
                }
            }
            else{
                status=1;
            }
            if(status == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Line no 402");
            }

        }
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Return Operation Finished.");
        //saveData();
    }

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static int objCount=0;

public static int getObjCount()
{
    return objCount;
}
```

}

And finally you could have your main runner class which executes all the code :

```
public class CreateLibrary {
    static final String username = "";
    static final String password = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception

{
    BufferedReader scan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter User Name: ");
    String enterUser= scan.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
    String enterPass =scan.readLine();


    if(enterUser.equals(username) && enterPass.equals(password))
    {
        System.out.println("Login Successful...\n\n");
        Library library = new Library();

        int choice=0;
        while(choice!=7)
        {
            System.out.println("Select From Below Options: ");
            System.out.println("1. Add Book\n2. Modify Book\n3. Delete Book\n4. Search Book\n5. Issue Book\n6. Return Book\n7. LogOut");
            System.out.println("Enter Your Choice: ");
            choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Book book = new Book();
                        System.out.println("_________________Enter Book Details_________________");
                        System.out.println(" Enter title of the Book    : ");
                        book.setBookTitle(scan.readLine());
                        System.out.println(" Enter the Name of Author   : ");
                        book.setBookAuthor(scan.readLine());
                        System.out.println(" Enter the Subject of Book  : ");
                        book.setBookSubject(scan.readLine());
                        System.out.println(" Enter the Price of Book    : ");
                        book.setBookPrice(Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine()));
                        System.out.println(" Enter Number of Copies     :");
                        book.setNoOfCopies(Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine()));                            
                        library.addBook(book);
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter Index of Book you want to Modify: ");
                        int index=Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine()); 

                        System.out.println("_________________Modify Book_________________");
                        System.out.println("Enter Title of Book to Modify: ");
                        String title = scan.readLine();

                        System.out.println("Enter New Price of Book: ");
                        double price = Double.parseDouble(scan.readLine());

                        System.out.println("Enter New Available copies of Book");
                        int availableCopies = Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());

                        library.modifyBook(index,title,price,availableCopies);
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter Index of Book you want to Delete: ");
                        int index=Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());

                        System.out.println("_________________Delete Book_________________");
                        System.out.println("Enter Title of Book to delete: ");
                        String title = scan.readLine();

                        library.deleteBook(index,title);
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter Index of Book you want to Search: ");
                        int index=Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());

                        System.out.println("_________________Search Book_________________");
                        System.out.println("Enter Title of Book to Search: ");
                        String title = scan.readLine();

                        library.searchBook(index,title);
                        break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter Index of Book you want to Issue: ");
                        int index=Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());

                        System.out.println("_________________Issue Book_________________");
                        System.out.println("Enter Title of Book  :  ");
                        String title = scan.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Enter Name of Student:  ");
                        String studName = scan.readLine();

                        library.issueBook(index,title,studName);
                        break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter Index of Book you want to Return: ");
                        int index=Integer.parseInt(scan.readLine());

                        System.out.println("_________________Return Book_________________");
                        System.out.println("Enter Title of Book  :  ");
                        String title = scan.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Enter Name of Student:  ");
                        String studName = scan.readLine();

                        library.returnBook(index,title,studName);
                        break;
                    }
                case 7:
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    } //if bracket
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Login Credentials. It's not that easy to get in.");
        System.out.print("Quiting...");
        Thread.sleep(800);

    }
}
```

}

Hope that helps.

Comment: I will check and tell you.

Comment: What about serializtion

Comment: and I need to store objects into arraylist….

Comment: All book objects are present inside an ArrayList in a Library object.

Comment: Serialisation happens as it was happening. Go through the entire code once.

Comment: Can you just copy all my code from my paste bin links and do changes and reupload to paste bin

Comment: I cant get what you are saying and where is serialization code

Comment: Im getting error while compiling Library.java: Library.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    public static ArrayList<Books> bookData = new ArrayList<Books>();

Comment: Getting error while compiling CreateLibrary.java
`CreateLibrary.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
                                                        Books book = new Books();`

Comment: Try adding these files to eclipse and then run. Eclipse will point out all errors and it will be easy for you to resolve them.